# How to permanenty save sub interface IP (logic/virual interface) on solaris

Tags: solaris-10

I am using Solaris 10.
I want to add sub interface (including ip and mask) and save it to keep it when server reboot (Ex: Bge0:1, Bge0:2...)

General, I am use NetConf to add sub interface and assign iP for it, but it is too long for add multiple Interfaces.

Is there other way to do it like creating a file and runing it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add in `/etc` files like  `hostname.bge0:1` and so on with appropriate information

```
yourhostname netmask + broadcast + up
```

Also you need to add in `/etc/hosts` pairs for those hostnames

```
<your IP> yourhostname
```

Then plumb the interface

```
ifconfig bge0:1 plumb
```

and then up it

```
ifconfig bge0:1 `cat /etc/hostname.bge0:1`
```

Do not forget to add appropriate netmask record in `/etc/netmasks`

```
<your IP network> <your IP network netmask>
```